# Access Repeater values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, repeater

i searched a lot on NET, to get the solution, but i could not find

Can anyone tell me how to access the label and textbox values of repeater control inside using the javascript ?

This is my code

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table id="t1" width="200px:" style="background-color: skyblue" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid")%>'
                        runat="server" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid")%>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ename")%>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now i want to access the label, textbox of repeater using javascript

@Diodeus

I tried your code

```
function submitAll() {
        var thisLabel = $('.myLabel').eq(0);
        alert(thisLabel);
    }
```

But i got the result in alert as

[object Object]

and @deostroll

I tried your code this way

But not getting anything

```
    function GetData() {
        var arrTables = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('table');
        var tbl = arrTables[0];
        var td = tbl.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
        var txt = td.childNodes[0];
        alert(txt.value);        
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid")%>'></asp:Label>
```

IDs must be unique, so you can't apply the same ID to all of the labels in your repeater. Use CSS class names instead.

```
<asp:Label CssClass="myLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid")%>'></asp:Label>
```

Since jQuery comes with .NET you can use it instead of plain JavaScript to access these elements more easily.

`var thisLabel = $('.myLabel').eq(0)` where 0 is the index of the element since there can be many.

Comment: I m not able to post code how to post code? its being posted like paragraph

Comment: <code> function submitAll() {
            var thisLabel = $('.myLabel').eq(0);
            alert(thisLabel);
        } </code>

Comment: but on alert i got [object Object]

Comment: Yes, that gives you a reference to the object. You can get the value with $('.myLabel').eq(0).text() or $('.myLabel').eq(0).html()

Comment: Awsome. :) but its just giving single value, i have to get all the values so how can i get the count of rows of repeater so i can use it in for loop

Comment: $('.myLabel').length will give you a count so you can use a loop: replace .eq(0) with your counter .eq(x)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the repeater in a div with some id, say myDiv.

```
<div id="myDiv">
<!-- your repeater code -->
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"...>
<ItemTemplate>
<table>...</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Do a

```
var arrTables = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('table');
```

Now `arrTables` is just array of all table elements inside the div. Find the ordinal of the desired table: For e.g. sake I am taking first table.

```
var tbl = arrTables[0];
```

Find the corresponding *td* of the table element:

```
var td = tbl.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
```

The above may vary based on how your browser loads the DOM and stuff. Hence I say you debug and find out for your self.

Once you get the *td* reference:

```
var txt = td.childNodes[0];
```

This will give the textbox. `txt.nextSibling` will give the label...and so on.

Comment: I tried your code but not getting it , i put the <table> of repeater inside the <div id="mydiv"><table>.. and write the code this way                                                        function GetData() {
            var arrTables = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('table');
            var tbl = arrTables[0];
            var td = tbl.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
            var txt = td.childNodes[0];

            alert(txt.value);
        
        }