# How to get text of a particular lable placed inside a repeater in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a repeater and a lable inside the repeater, that is binded with a table having 5 row each row has username that is binded to lable control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PostsRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("username") %>"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input id="btnGetUser" type="button" value="Get" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

i want to get the name of user that has some values in the textbox on button click using javascript

Comment: foreach (Repeater objRepe in Repeater1.Items)
{
      Label Name= (Label)item.FindControl("Name");
      if(Name!=null)
      {
      //Your Code
      }
      Image img= (Image)objRepe.FindControl("Img");
      if(img!=null)
      {
      //your code
      }
}

Comment: can u please give me javascript code on button click??

Comment: try this..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342583/access-repeater-values-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<asp:Label..>` ware rendered as html `span` tags. Since the labels are inside the  `<asp:Repeater..>` they will named in the following manner:

Span id will be dynamically generated as `"repeater_id" + "_" + "ctl00" + "_" + label_id` So in your case the id for label in the first row will be:  `"PostsRepeater_ctl00_lblUserName"` You can simply inspect the element and check for the id. you can write events based on this `id` inside script or can iterate through all labels by following code: subject to the condition that you need to specify `cssClass` for labels as `rptLabels`

```
var elemArray = document.getElementsByClassName('rptLabels');
for(var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++){
    var elem = elemArray[i]; // this will be your label
   alert(elem.innerText); 
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/zt4r9aer/)

Comment: how can i get the text of elem?

Comment: use  `elem.innerText` to get text from `Span`; see the updates